# Duplicate keyboard typing to another terminal

Tags: linux, terminal

I have laptop-desktop setup at home and I have successfully cloned my Archlinux installation from one to another. However, I would like to avoid having to {install all new software, edit settings, update} twice, so I was wondering if it'd be possible to log over ssh from laptop to desktop, do something in terminal and have linux copy everything I type into second terminal with ssh logged in?

Thanks for ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could type the commands into one terminal then edit ~/.bash_history and save the commands into a script.  Copy the script onto the machine with the second terminal and execute it.  The advantage of this is now you have a script that saved your setup so you can reuse it whenever you need to.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do the trick, although I was wondering if there were some "terminal-actions-duplicating" tool.

Comment: You may be able to do it by piping your input into [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect).

Answer (score 0):

You can use clusterssh, which duplicates your typed input across multiple systems.  It is designed for situations in which the exact same tasks, such as software installation or configuration commands, are needed to be performed exactly the same on multiple systems.  See http://sourceforge.net/projects/clusterssh/.  Also, the KDE Konsole terminal has similar functionality.